# Strange error message when using SaveChanges in EF with MVC

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a `dropdownlistfor` with values that is not from my database, and when a user select values that does not exist in my database, I want to save it to the database(and if it already exist, I just use the existing data).

This work fine with some of my data(see code for where it does not work)

This is my repository:

```
 public void newPerson(Person addperson)
    {
        db.Person.AddObject(addperson);
        db.SaveChanges(); //This wont work
    }
```

here is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CreateNKIphase1ViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var goalcard = new GoalCard();

            var companyChecker = "";
            var dbCompanies = createNKIRep.GetCustomerByName();
            var addcustomer = new Customer();
            foreach (var existingcustomer in dbCompanies)
            {
                companyChecker = existingcustomer.CompanyName;
                    if (existingcustomer.CompanyName == model.CompanyName)
                    {
                        var customerId = existingcustomer.Id;
                        var selectedCustomerID = createNKIRep.GetByCustomerID(customerId);
                        goalcard.Customer = selectedCustomerID;
                        break;
                    }
            }
            if (companyChecker != model.CompanyName)
            {
                addcustomer.CompanyName = model.CompanyName;
                createNKIRep.newCustomer(addcustomer); //This works!
                goalcard.Customer = addcustomer;
            }

            if (model.PersonName != null)
            {
                var Personchecker = "";
                var dbPersons = createNKIRep.GetPersonsByName();

                foreach (var existingPerson in dbPersons)
                {
                    Personchecker = existingPerson.Name;
                    if (existingPerson.Name == model.PersonName)
                    {
                        var personId = existingPerson.Id;
                        var selectedPersonID = createNKIRep.GetByPersonID(personId);
                        goalcard.Person = selectedPersonID;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (Personchecker != model.PersonName)
                {
                    Person newPerson = new Person();
                    newPerson.Name = model.PersonName;
                    createNKIRep.newPerson(newPerson);//Where repository is called
                    goalcard.Person = newPerson;
                }
            }
```

But when I try to save a new `Person` I get the following error message:

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
>   The statement has been terminated.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Even though `Person` only have `Id` and `name` as attributes in my database.

Is there anything wrong in my code, or is it any setting in my database that has to be changed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like something to do with your Db to me. What structure is your Person table? It doesn't contain any datetime fields? any foriegn keys or triggers?

Comment: It has a navigation property to `Goalcard`. And just the attributes `ID`and `Name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because I use `db.SaveChanges();` multiple times in one `post`. Reducing numbers of time I use `db.SaveChanges` helped me get rid of the error.